# Is there a way to keep user logged in to Azure ADB2C when they attempt to link a social account and click cancel?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

When someone goes to link their social media account to their ADB2C registration, we have a problem whereby we are unable to distinguish between a failed ADB2C sign in, and the cancellation of their request to link their social media account.

When someone, for example, tries to link their Facebook account, a URL like this sits behind the 'Not now' link:

```
https://test.b2clogin.com/test.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&state=StateProperties%3DeyJTSUQiOiJ4LW1zLWNwaW0tcmM6NzMyYWQzZWXtZGI4OS00YjZiLTlmYzgtYTY5NzYxZDdjMDY0IiwiVElEIjoiNTcxZWE5M2UtODQ4NS00MTMzLTlhZmItOTQwMWIyMDAwOGE5IiwiVE9JRCI6Ijc4ZDUxNTY3LTkzYTAtNDEyMy1iMHI1LTVmN2E1NzNjMzRkYSJ9#_=_
```

We trap the [AuthenticationFailedNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn800255(v=vs.113)), but within it, we haven't been able to find a way to distinguish between

- an access denied message based on the cancellation of the request to link a social media account, and
- an actual genuine access denied response.

We check:

```
if (notification.ProtocolMessage.Error == "access_denied" && notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.StartsWith("[A SPECIFIC ERROR ID]", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

We would then have a specific user flow configured for each scenario, based on the error description, authentication policy and authentication type (social media or ADB2C).

Our requirement is for the user to remain logged in to ADB2C when they attempt to link a social account, but don't actually go through with it.

Microsoft's own example, https://woodgrovedemo.com/ works in the same way, whereby the user is logged out when they cancel the linking of their social media account (for example, by clicking 'Not now' when going to link their Facebook account).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because it's the same thing!

When a user cancel the Facebook process with the 'Not now' button, the user ain't logged in. You need the user to accept to be link to your app for Facebook to send an approbation and a claims to be delivered to your app. Without this claims, the user is not logged in.

So you can't have a requirement to keep the user logged in, since he haven't been logged in yet. It's false to think that the Microsoft's example logged out the user, since he was never logged in.